# Change the data used in a force layout

Tags: d3.js, transition

I have a force layout based on [this block by Mike Bostock](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062045)

First I get my data :

```
var dataNetwork = creationTableaux(seuil);
```

Where creationTableaux is a function that gives me my data, depending on the number of nodes and links I want

Then I create the simulation

```
        var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
            .force("link", d3.forceLink().id(d => d.id))
            .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody().strength(-250))
            .force("center", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2));

        var link = canevas2.append("g")
        .attr("class", "links")
        .selectAll("line")
        .data(dataNetwork.links)
        .enter()
        .append("line")
        .attr("stroke", "lightblue")
        .attr("stroke-width", d => 6 * d.value);

        var node = canevas2.append("g")
        .attr("class", "nodes")
        .selectAll("circle")
        .data(dataNetwork.nodes)
        .enter()
        .append("circle")
        .attr("r", 5)
        .attr("fill", "lightblue");

        simulation.nodes(dataNetwork.nodes).on("tick", ticked);

        simulation.force("link").links(dataNetwork.links);

        function ticked() {
            link
                .attr("x1", function(d) {
                    return d.source.x;
                })
                .attr("y1", function(d) {
                    return d.source.y;
                })
                .attr("x2", function(d) {
                    return d.target.x;
                })
                .attr("y2", function(d) {
                    return d.target.y;
                });

            node
                .attr("cx", function(d) {
                    return d.x;
                })
                .attr("cy", function(d) {
                    return d.y;
                });
        }
```

This works perfectly fine, so I know that (at least!) this is right. Now the thing is all of this is included in another function, in which I can inject different csv files, whose links and nodes and whatnot are then drawn. I call this function with a button, and for instance when I call the function twice, both of the graphs are on my page at the same time.

I tried to follow a few examples, like [this one](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1095795), but I'm stuck. I know that the problem comes from the fact that all the nodes and links are called using `enter()` and that there should be an `exit().remove()` somewhere in there, but how I should fix this is a mystery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally found a way of doing that. Before launching the simulation I simply had to remove all pre-existing elements.

```
canevas2.selectAll("line").remove();
canevas2.selectAll("circle").remove();
canevas2.selectAll("text").remove();
```

Can't see why I didn't think about it before !

edit : the downside to this method of course it that the "transition" (if it can be called a transition) won't be very smooth, since the diagram will be redrawn every time. But it's better than nothing :)